# oracle sql command for finding TOP 10 and LEAST 10 salaried from EMPLOYEES TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I like to find TOP 10 and LEAST 10 salary of employees. The output should show the TOP 10 and LEAST 10 salaried employees together

I got the TOP 10 salary employees in one sql command and found LEAST 10 salary employees in another sql command. how to combine them

```
SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT *FROM emp 
    ORDER BY Salary desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 10
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

and

```
SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT *FROM emp 
    ORDER BY Salary asc 
    )
WHERE rownum <= 10
ORDER BY Salary asc;
```

output should give 20 people combining 10 highest and 10 lowest

Answer (score 2):

use `union all`

```
SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT *FROM emp 
    ORDER BY Salary desc
    )
WHERE rownum <= 10
union all
SELECT  *FROM 
    (
    SELECT *FROM emp 
    ORDER BY Salary asc 
    )
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774636/1509264) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47420554/1509264). Please take the time to search for duplicates and vote to close the question if you find any.

Comment: yes, from the next time I'll @MT0

Answer (score 1):

One method `union all`.  Another uses window functions, which I prefer:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as seqnum_desc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as seqnum_asc
      FROM emp e 
     ) e
WHERE seqnum_desc <= 10 or seqnum_asc <= 10
ORDER BY Salary ;
```

Note:  If there are ties, this will arbitrarily choose 10 rows from each group.  If you want all rows in the event of ties, then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774636/1509264) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420895/1509264). Please take the time to search for duplicates and close the question if you find any.

Answer (score 1):

use `union all` with `row_numer()`

```
SELECT  a.* FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,row_number() over(order by Salary desc) rn FROM emp 

    ) a
WHERE rn <= 10
union all
SELECT  b.* FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,row_number() over(order by Salary asc) rn FROM emp 

    ) b
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Comment: This is missing the `ORDER BY` keywords in the analytic functions. It is also a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420895/1509264); please take the time to search for duplicates and vote to close the question if you find any.